# RNCryptor bytes missing from end of file

Tags: encryption, rncryptor

Using RNCryptor to encrypt and decrypt a file and have an issue that I don't seem to be getting the complete file back.

My encrypt is as follows

```
- (void) encryptDownloadedFile:(NSString*)filename
{
    NSString *outputTmpFilePath = [downloadCacheDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.mov", filename]];

    int blockSize = 32 * 1024;

    __block NSInputStream *plainTextStream = [NSInputStream inputStreamWithData:[downloadFileStream propertyForKey:NSStreamDataWrittenToMemoryStreamKey]];
    __block NSOutputStream *encryptedStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:outputTmpFilePath append:NO];
    __block NSMutableData *downloadedFileData = [NSMutableData data];

    [plainTextStream open];
    [encryptedStream open];

    __block NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:blockSize];
    __block RNEncryptor *encryptor = nil;

    dispatch_block_t readStreamBlock = ^{
        [data setLength:blockSize];
        NSInteger bytesRead = [plainTextStream read:[data mutableBytes] maxLength:blockSize];

        if (bytesRead < 0) {
            // Throw an error
        }

        else if (bytesRead == 0) {
            [encryptor finish];

            [downloadedFileData writeToFile:outputTmpFilePath atomically:YES];

            [plainTextStream close];
            [encryptedStream close];
            [downloadFileStream close];
            plainTextStream = nil;
            encryptedStream = nil;
            downloadFileStream = nil;

        }
        else {
            [data setLength:bytesRead];
            [encryptor addData:data];
        }
    };

    encryptor = [[RNEncryptor alloc] initWithSettings:kRNCryptorAES256Settings
                                         password:@"blah"
                                          handler:^(RNCryptor *cryptor, NSData *data)     {

                                                  [downloadedFileData appendBytes:data.bytes length:data.length];

                                                  if (cryptor.isFinished) {

                                                  }
                                                  else {
                                                      readStreamBlock();
                                                  }
                                              }];
    readStreamBlock();
}
```

Pretty much standard from the example on the RNCryptor git page. The input file is a downloaded file that was grabbed earlier with

```
downloadFileStream = [[NSOutputStream alloc] initToMemory];
```

Decrypt for completeness is here

```
- (void) decryptDownloadedFile:(NSString*)filename
{
    NSString *inputTmpFilePath = [downloadCacheDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.mov", filename]];
    NSString *outputTmpFilePath = [downloadCacheDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"decrypted%@.mov", filename]];

    int blockSize = 32 * 1024;

    NSInputStream *cryptedStream = [NSInputStream inputStreamWithFileAtPath:inputTmpFilePath];
    NSOutputStream *decryptedStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:outputTmpFilePath append:NO];

    [cryptedStream open];
    [decryptedStream open];

    __block NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:blockSize];
    __block RNDecryptor *decryptor = nil;

    dispatch_block_t readStreamBlock = ^{
        [data setLength:blockSize];
        NSInteger bytesRead = [cryptedStream read:[data mutableBytes] maxLength:blockSize];
        if (bytesRead < 0) {
            // Throw an error
        }
        else if (bytesRead == 0) {
            [decryptor finish];

            [decryptedStream close];
        }
        else {
            [data setLength:bytesRead];
            [decryptor addData:data];
        }
    };

    decryptor = [[RNDecryptor alloc] initWithPassword:@"blah"
                                          handler:^(RNCryptor *cryptor, NSData *data)     {
                                                  [decryptedStream write:data.bytes maxLength:data.length];
                                                  if (cryptor.isFinished) {

                                                  }
                                                  else {
                                                      readStreamBlock();
                                                  }
                                              }];
    readStreamBlock();    
}
```

Again very similar to the git page.

However, I am 60 bytes short at the tail when I encrypt and decrypt the same file. Not a huge issue until I start to finesse this to support resumable downloads. Then the missing bytes are critical as they appear in the centre of the file.

I have checked what is coming in and out as below

- Bytes being sent to the encryptor 19,615,005 (the size of the file)
- Encrypted bytes created by the encryptor 19,615,026
- Bytes received by the decrypt or 19,615,026
- Decrypted bytes from the decryptor 19,614,944

I have tried

1. Changing the .options = kCCOptionPKCS7Padding in RNCryptor.h
2. Tried padding to the block size and to a 16 byte boundary myself
3. Changed the encryptor finish and readStreamBlock calls to make sure its not a timing issue
4. Investigated finishWithError in RNCryptorEngine, but there are no errors

Padding to the block size sort of works as I can then clean up the zeros that I padded with, but its not ideal.

I am scratching my head. Anyone been through this loop before?

**Update:**

Spent a long time scratching my head and realised I don't have the capability to figure out the issue in a  timely fashion. However, I stepped backwards to the simple solution and this works, but not for me as this gives me memory issues.

```
- (void) simpleEncrypt:(NSString*)filename
{
    NSLogDebug(@"simpleEncrypt");

    NSString *outputTmpFilePath = [downloadCacheDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.mov", filename]];

    NSData *data = [downloadFileStream propertyForKey:NSStreamDataWrittenToMemoryStreamKey];
    NSError *error;
    NSData *encryptedData = [RNEncryptor encryptData:data
                                    withSettings:kRNCryptorAES256Settings
                                        password:@"blah"
                                           error:&error];

    [encryptedData writeToFile:outputTmpFilePath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];

    NSLogDebug(@"simpleEncrypt isFinished");
}

- (void) simpleDecrypt:(NSString*)filename
{
    NSLogDebug(@"simpleDecrypt");

    NSString *inputTmpFilePath = [downloadCacheDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.mov", filename]];
    NSString *outputTmpFilePath = [downloadCacheDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"decrypted%@.mov", filename]];

    NSData *encryptedData = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:inputTmpFilePath];

    NSError *error;
    NSData *decryptedData = [RNDecryptor decryptData:encryptedData
                                    withPassword:@"blah"
                                           error:&error];

    [decryptedData writeToFile:outputTmpFilePath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];

    NSLogDebug(@"simpleDecrypt isFinished");
}
```

If I mix it with the previous solution I get the same problem.

Comment: I'm not good at reading Objective-C - but i do know the symptoms of the final decrypt. .. do you remember to get the last encrypted data produced by the decrypter after calling finish? Decrypter modules holds on to the last bit of data until it can be determined if it's padding or real data.

Comment: Ebbe, went back to the CCCryptorFinal in the RNCryptor finishWithError but as far as I can see it seems to be doing what is expected. Have parked this now and may come back to it later.

Comment: Well in the end I fudged it with a fileMgr copyItemAtPath: to copy the output from the decryptedStream to another file. This seems to flush out the final few bytes from where ever they were hiding. If anyone has a better solution let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You moved the stream close, and this is probably the problem. In the example linked, in `readStreamBlock`, there is this code:

```
else if (bytesRead == 0) {
 [decryptor finish];
}
```

then inside the decryption handler, there is this code:

```
                                        if (cryptor.isFinished) {
                                          [decryptedStream close];
                                          // call my delegate that I'm finished with decrypting
                                        }
```

You moved the close into `readStreamBlock`:

```
    else if (bytesRead == 0) {
        [decryptor finish];

        [decryptedStream close];
    }
```

That means that the stream is closed before the asynchronous decryption completes.

Comment: That doesn't appear to be the issue. The code posted above I admit has the change you note, but I have it the other way round in code, as you describe. Significant to me is that with the close in the right place, running in the simulator, the size of the completed file reported by a call to the NSFileManager file attributes is smaller (19,614,944) than that shown by Finder (19,615,005). I am beginning to think this is a NSOutputStream issue as copying the file as mentioned fixes the issue.

Comment: Also, whilst working through this I kept hitting memory issues. I wrote my own byte by byte file copier to fix the copyItemAtPath memory issue. But also added @autorelease pools to RNCryptorEngine addData, RNDecryptor decryptData and RNEncryptor addData.

Comment: Mea Culpa. Had a doh moment this morning. Rob is correct, although I was closing the stream in the correct place what I hadn't done is call the next step of my file processing from the same place, I had called it from within the readStreamBlock. Therefore the next step in my process was starting before the encryption had completed. I hadn't actually shown this in the example code.